# navigate inside a jQuery modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I got a question. I'm using the [jQuery modal dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) plugin to let user input some data that will be saved in a database. My dialog can actually have two states which users can choose from by selecting a radio button inside the dialog box. The problem I'm having is that I lose some of the styles on my dialog box when the user selects a radio button. Also, how do I make it so that when the user saves the input data on the dialog box, after the dialog has closed, I want to load the new data live on the current page (with without the user having to refresh the page to see the changes).

Any idea?

Comment: Definitely need more indication of how you've implemented all this - some markup, code, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the other guys, you should give us some code for your first question.

For your second question, The jQuery Modal Dialog plugin picks up a div from the DOM and converts it to the modal dialog. So all the controls which are available inside the modal dialog can be access with normal jQuery.

Also, you can assign a function to be executed when the OK or Cancel buttons are clicked inside the modal dialog. Have a look here:http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-buttons

So what you can do is, when the "OK" button is clicked, your function will pickup all the values which are inside the controls on the modal dialog and assign them to the controls on the current page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What do you mean by "the controls on the current page"? When the dialog is open, the background page freezes, it's no longer in focus, I can't access anything on it

Comment: Yes. Even though it freezes, you can still access it with jQuery or the JavaScript getElements methods. Try it out.